# MySQL differential backup script

Tags: mysql

I have been asked to implement MySQL differential backup for our client database backup. It should be able to achieve a better restore plan in windows.

How can i do this in windows  ?

Comment: Short answer: hire a developer (because it's work for developer). Longer answer - please, read [help] page

Comment: I have google it but no luck. Anyone pointer to achieving MySQL differential backup in windows?